# Can Fragments use the logic from main_activity.java?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So, I am using Activity Recognition API to know the state of the user, and implementing it like Google FIT does.

I have written all the logic for the app in main_activity.java and a class I made for ActivityRecognition. And I have my XML in activity_main.xml

PRetty usual stuff till now.

Well the problem arises now when I want to integrate the code in Tab layout material design which uses fragments and viewpager to display.

If I copy my activity_main.xml to Fragment_one.xml, Do I have to copy the logic for ActivityRecognition API to Fragment_one.java too or not ?

Very confused, any help will do.

Comment: If it's just a class, and it sounds like it is, it can be imported into any other class along with the rest of the imports.  You just need to be sure that the vars you need are declared publicly.

Comment: If you need an example of how you can use methods from outside classes, take a look at this:  http://goo.gl/eBsyy6

Comment: they can...simplest way is typecast it using getActivity() and the call your methods.
Or use the interface listener pattern between fragments and activities.